# SQL Server and binary data - Performance impact?

Tags: sql-server

I have some parts in my software which are high customizable. I store them with MsgPack (binary stream / array) in SQL Server 2012. In most cases they are bellow 8096byte – but in 30% they are above (lets say 5x bigger than the page). I read about issues with Row-Overflow.

How big is the performance impact on it?
Is it a bad design?
Is SQL Server 2012 ok for mixed environments (RDBMS + NoSQL)?

Comment: An option may be [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx)

Comment: FILESTREAM is very slow - isnt it?

Comment: Its transactional - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356154/file-stream-vs-local-save-in-sql-server. If you're on Azure there is also the Table Blob storage for NoSql.

Comment: The MS reserach link was nice - thx. Table Blob is not an option - its a local installation