# MySQL database schema creator & owner relationship? For example user & media?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, mysql-workbench

What is the best way to link two tables together if there is a creator and owner relationship between them? For example a user create a media file entry. A user optionally has an image / media file as a profile picture. I've built a schema with MySQL Workbench. But that way it doesn't work. The other tables: A project has one or many bugs, a bug has one or many comments. Both bugs an comments can have one or many images / media files. Thanks!

[image: Mysql workbench wrong database schema]

Comment: Can a media be used in one bug or one comment? Or it can be used in many bugs or comments too?

Comment: At first, no media library is planned. But in the future I think it would make sense that you can reuse media in bugs and comments. So I used here a n:m relationship. But don't know how to the user <-> media relationship can be realised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**:
Based on you explanation, you Database Design should be like this (UML notation):

[image]

> a user create a media file entry.

So you have a `creator_user_id` as F.K into `media`. It **can not** be `null` and each media should have a creator.

> A user **optionally** has an image / media file as a profile picture.

So you have one-to-one relationship between user and media. You have two options:

1. move user id as F.K to media as `profile_user_id` and make it `Allow NULL` and `Unique`.
2. move media id as F.K to user as `profile_media_id` and make it `Allow NULL` and `Unique`.

Both is correct.

For example (second option), you can have a `profile_media_id` as F.K into `user`. It **can** be `null`. **But** it should be `unique`. Means that a `media` can be appears only in one user profile.

This design (second option) is not wrong. It looks a **circular reference**. But, when you are adding a new user with a profile image (at the same time), you should perform these actions in one **transaction**:

1. create a user (and let the `profile_media_id` to be `null`)
2. create a media with new `creator_user_id`
3. update the new user `profile_media_id`

**Secondly**: 
 
Your second parts of design (relationships between media and post and bug) looks good. (based on your explanations)

However, I offer designing a whole external media management system for them (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022799/database-model-to-manage-documents/48024413#48024413)).

### EDIT

you can use something like below to create your tables:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myuser;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

CREATE TABLE myuser(
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    profile_media_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mymedia;
CREATE TABLE mymedia(
    media_id INT NOT NULL,
    creator_user_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (media_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (creator_user_id) REFERENCES myuser (user_id),
    UNIQUE (creator_user_id)
);

ALTER TABLE myuser ADD CONSTRAINT myusermymediafk FOREIGN KEY (profile_media_id) REFERENCES mymedia (media_id);
```

See [MySQL test here](http://rextester.com/KTPEZ8338).

Comment: Hello Gholamali-Irani,

I tried it this way on my MariaDB (Xampp via phpMyAdmin import). But here the create table statement issue an error:

Can't create table `dbname`.`user` (Fehler: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"). Referenced table `dbname`.`media` not found in the data dictionary near.

So I can't create this schema because there reciprocal relationship. Is there an other clean way for MySQL / MariaDB - or have I to use n:m schema or delete the creator user logging field?

Comment: Please see the example added.